# Definir timeout na execução de threads e guardar valor de retorno

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

Olá,

Tenho um serviço web, com backend em java 7. Num dado momento, o backend faz uma chamada RPC em broadcast para **N** servidores que estão à escuta. Só que não existe timeout pré-definido na chamada, não tenho forma de controlar o tempo de resposta dos **N** servidores. Não tenho acesso ao código-fonte dos **N** servidores.

```
result = RPC.call(params, liveAddresses, conf);
```

A solução proposta era converter o código para multi-threading, criando **N** threads. Cada uma fica responsável por chamar 1 endereço (servidor).
Se seguir a estratégia anterior:

É possível em java lançar várias threads com um tempo máximo de espera que cada uma termine. Recebendo a thread main o resultados de todas as threads ?

Aceito ideias para outras estratégias a seguir.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria a utilização do [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Exemplo Básico:

RpcResult.class:

```
public class RpcResult {

  private int clientId;
  private String response;

  // getters and setters...
}
```

RpcExecutor.class:

```
public class RpcExecutor implements Callable<RpcResult>{

  private int clientId;

  public RpcExecutor(int clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }

  public RpcResult call() throws Exception {    
    RpcResult result = new RpcResult();
    result.setClientId(clientId);
    result.setResponse("Resposta do cliente: " + clientId);

    return result;
  }

}
```

Execução:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);             
List<Callable<RpcResult>> list = new ArrayList<Callable<RpcResult>>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  list.add(new RpcExecutor(i));        
}

// 3 segundos de timeout
List<Future<RpcResult>> future = executor.invokeAll(list, 3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

for(Future<RpcResult> f : future) {           
  try {
    if (!f.isCancelled()) {
      RpcResult result = f.get();
      System.out.println(result.getClientId());
      System.out.println(result.getResponse());
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }      
};

executor.shutdown();
```

Pra simular o timeout de um cliente basta adicionar um Thread.sleep() no método call() da classe RpcExecutor:

```
public RpcResult call() throws Exception {
    if (clientId == 2)
        Thread.sleep(15000);

    RpcResult result = new RpcResult();
    result.setClientId(clientId);
    result.setResponse("Resposta do cliente: " + clientId);

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**

---

De acordo com as novas informações relacionadas a estrutura atual do projeto, essa solução não teria escalabilidade.

Se você tem em mente que sua aplicação nunca terá muitos usuários, ok, vá na solução mais simples. Agora, se sua aplicação precisa escalar, essa poderia ser uma das alternativas(modelo simplificado):

[image: Async Arch]

Comment: Desde já, obrigado pela resposta. Esqueci me de dizer na pergunta que se trata de Java7. O stream do future penso que seja java 8. O maior problema que tenho é não ter acesso ao código fonte do método do call(). Mas posso usar a lógica do executor para chamar. O invokeall posso definir o timeout ? Já agora outra questão que me perturba, Estamos a falar de um código de uma servlet, criar N threads para cada client não pode criar problema de performance?

Comment: @user2989745 1 - Em relação ao stream, basta você usar um "for" no Java7, editei a resposta. 2 - Você pode definir o timeout do invokeAll. 3 - Já que é uma aplicação web, essa solução não é muito escalável. Imagine que você tenha que consultar 30 clientes e que você inicie uma thread por cliente (30 threads por requests), então se sua aplicação recebe 100 requests, seria 100 * 30 threads abertas. Eu partiria pra uma solução assíncrona solicitando essas consultas para uma outra aplicação e o client poderia receber a resposta por websocket...

Comment: Obrigado! Sim foi o que pensei, queria outra opinião. Podes aprofundar a tua estrutura ? O que ganharia com o assincrono ? A acção é despoletada por um click num botão no front-end. Não sei como controlar melhor o tempo de resposta RPC....

Comment: @user2989745 O que você ganha com uma solução assíncrona, é que você não segura um request no seu server aguardando respostas de serviços de terceiros que você não sabe em quanto tempo vão responder. Atualizei minha resposta pra te dar uma ideia de como seria, claro, ficaria bem mais complexa a plataforma.

Comment: Sim estou a perceber onde o assincrono pode ajudar. Percebo a tua ideia, e parace me uma boa ideia.  Vou estudar melhor WebSockets, para ver como se encaixa. Mas sim, ideia interessante, obrigado pela explicação.